# Как прижать background к низу ?

Tags: css

Можно ли как нибудь, с помощью css прижать background к низу ?

[image: img]

Comment: Читаем про [background-position][1]

   [1]:http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

Answer (score 3):

Тут что то не ясно, либо:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

или

```
background-position: right bottom;
```